# Force an AR object to always stand upright in Unity / Vuforia

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have a Unity AR project using Vuforia engine. What I am trying to achieve is to have the AR object always stand upright in the view whether the image target is horizontal on a table or or vertical on a wall.

Currently the object is sitting on the image target no matter which orientation

Hope that makes sense,

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use [`Vector3.ProjectOnPlane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ProjectOnPlane.html) for this and then you can simply assign axis directions to `Transform.up` and `Transform.right` (below I explain why `right` and not maybe `forward`)

```
public void AlignObject(Transform obj, Transform imageTarget)
{
    obj.position = imageTarget.position;

    // Get your targets right vector in world space
    var right = imageTarget.right;

    // If not anyway the case ensure that your objects up vector equals the world up vector
    obj.up = Vector3.up;

    // Align your objects right vector with the image target's right vector
    // projected down onto the global XZ plane => erasing its Y component
    obj.right = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(right, Vector3.up); 
}
```

The assumption for this is: The target is usually never rotated in the Z axis. If you want it upright on a wall you would usually rotate it around its X axis.

Therefore we can assume the the image target will never be rotated more then 90° on the Z axis (in which case the mapped vector would flip about 180°) and thus if we map the `right` vector down onto the global XZ plane it always still points in the correct direction regardless of any rotations in Y and X axes.

If we would use the `forward` instead we take the risk that due to tracking inaccuracies the vertical targets forward vector actually points a tiny little bit towards us so when we map it down onto the XZ plane it points backwards not forwards and the object is flipped by 180°.

So using `right` works for a horizontal and a vertical target.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this unfortunately did not solve the issue. The object orientation remains unchanged

Comment: @jrhall what do you mean unchanged? The code definitely changes the rotation of your image target is rotated ...

Comment: My image target is at world center and has no rotation. I have an empty GameObject as the child of the image target (this is zeroed out for position and rotation also) and my animated AR object as a child of that. I applied the code you gave me to the empty GO. The AR remains oriented to the image target the same way regardless of whether the target is horizontal or vertical.

Comment: -> don't make it a child of the target .. otherwise of course it will follow any rotation the parent object does ...

Comment: Thanks, that has done the trick! The object is more separated from the target in space, but I can live with that